# Is Scapelli actually Donkey Kong?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, super-mario-brothers, donkey-kong, super-mario-bros-1993

In the 1993 Super Mario Bros. film, we meet a secondary antagonist, Scapelli, who apparently is a professional rival to Mario and Luigi's plumbing business. Near the end of the film, Koopa de-evolves Scapelli into an business suit-wearing ape using a de-evolution gun.

I was watching this film again after many years and it suddenly occurred to me that Scapelli in ape form could actually represent Donkey Kong, a character who has drifted in and out of Mario stories over the years. Shortly after this movie came out, the Super Nintendo game Donkey Kong Country came out, in which the titular character wears a necktie for no obvious reason.

I know that the film itself did very poorly and that Nintendo has more or less washed their hands of the whole thing, but are there any indications, either in the movie itself or behind the scenes (e.g. interviews, deleted scenes, script revisions, etc.), that the writers intended to create an origin story for Donkey Kong?

Just to be clear, I'm not asking whether this is Nintendo's current official origin story for Donkey Kong (a business rival of Mario who was de-evolved into an ape by an invading army of intelligent dinosaurs from a parallel universe). It almost certainly is not. I'm asking if there is evidence that the writers, etc. of this film had Donkey Kong in mind when creating Scapelli.

Comment: The script has him as "D.K." Scapelli

Comment: You might also want to note that the 'DK' on Donkey Kong's tie doesn't actually stand for Donkey Kong. it is in fact the monkonian symbol for 'Hope'

Comment: {narrows his eyes at Valorum} Are you serious, or is this a Superman joke?